# Node.js routes, and async function

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cloudinary

I am having some problem with the cloudinary api in a nodejs route. below is my route followed by the generic error I am getting. I have googled and read and asked, now its Stack Overflows turn.

Currently running node 10.3

```
 router.put("/snake/:id", upload.single('image'), function(req, res){
    Snake.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, async function(err, updatedSnake){
        if (err){
            res.render("error");
        }else{
            if(req.file){
                try{
                await cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(updatedSnake.imageId);
                var result = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.file.path);
         req.body.image = result.secure_url;
        req.body.imageId = result.public_id;                  

                } catch (err){
                    return res.redirect('error');
                }
            }
            updatedSnake.save();
        }
    });
});
```

and the error

```
Snake.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, async function(err, updatedSnake)
                                       ^^^^^
SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes as Mr. Patrick said check the node version. You could go with a simple structure (ES6) like this though.

```
router.put('path', multer, async(req, res) =>{


     try() {

     await Snake.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.i) 

  let updatedSnake =await Snake.findOne({id:req.params.id})
//do upload

    } 
     catch(err) {
//handle errors
     } 

 })
```